# how to get both month and maximum salary of an employee

Tags: mysql

two tables. one contains employee id,name,designation..
second table contains id,month,salary.

I need to get an output for maximum salary with month and name, designation of an employee.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Please take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Considering the tables as below;

```
mysql> select * from T1;
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | Designation |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | a    | man         |
|  2 | b    | assis       |
|  3 | c    | serv        |
+----+------+-------------+
```

and

```
mysql> select * from T2;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | month | salary |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | jan   |   3000 |
|  2 | jan   |   2000 |
|  3 | jan   |   1000 |
|  1 | Feb   |   4000 |
|  2 | Feb   |   3000 |
|  3 | Feb   |   2000 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Your Requirement:
to get the "maximum salary with month and name, designation of an employee"

Query:

```
select name,Designation,max(salary) from T1 join T2 using (id)          
group by name;
```

Result:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
| name | Designation | max(salary) |
+------+-------------+-------------+
| a    | man         |        4000 |
| b    | assis       |        3000 |
| c    | serv        |        2000 |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

If you want maximum salary of each employee for every month:

Query:

```
select name,Designation,month,max(salary) from T1 join T2 using (id)     
group by name,month;
```

Result :

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------------+
| name | Designation | month | max(salary) |
+------+-------------+-------+-------------+
| a    | man         | Feb   |        4000 |
| a    | man         | jan   |        3000 |
| b    | assis       | Feb   |        3000 |
| b    | assis       | jan   |        2000 |
| c    | serv        | Feb   |        2000 |
| c    | serv        | jan   |        1000 |
+------+-------------+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT x1.month,e1.name,e1.designation,x1.salary FROM employee e1 JOIN (SELECT max(salary) 
as salary,month,name,employeeid FROM salary GROUP BY employeeid)x1 
ON x1.salary = e1.salary AND e1.id = x1.employeeid
```

Comment: i didnt get the result. can u explain pls

Comment: im having one table with employeeid,name,designation AND ANOTHER TABLE WITH employeeid,month,salary.. i need to get max salary,name and designation of an employee

Comment: 12:18:59 SELECT month,name,salary FROM job_details  ((SELECT max(salary)  as salary,month,name,employeeid FROM salary GROUP BY employeeid) ON job_details.salary = salary_details.salary AND job_details.id = salary_details.id Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '((SELECT max(salary)  as salary,month,name,employeeid FROM salary GROUP BY emplo' at line 2 0.016 sec

Comment: please share full table structure and desire output...please read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99703/where-should-i-ask-database-related-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,month,salary from
           (select t1.name,t2.month,t2.salary,max(t2.salary) over(partition 
            by t2.id) as max 
from emp as t1 inner join emp_salary as t2 on t1.id=t2.id) as t 
where salary=max;
```

Comment: Providing an explanation to your answer helps the user understand the issue.  Please review the SO new user guide.  Thank you.